# Correct tense in a following sentence

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

I want to say something like this: If I hadn't told you esrlier, thank you for everything.

Is it correctly written (grammar I mean). The past perfect sounds weird to me, so I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Generally we don't use *tell* with phrases of gratitude, we *say* them. I would use:

> If I **didn't say it** (to you) earlier, thank you for everything.

You don't need the "you" in the first part, because it is implied by the "thank you".